# Building code using JENKINS

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-job-builder

I have configured JENKINS on my local machine . Now I have to build my code which is on my machine.  I have searched but all asking for git url and all. Just need to build code in my local folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build your code with Jenkins, Jenkins will always need to clone your code even if your code is on the same machine.

Here's an example of local git repo that you can use for Jenkins on Windows :

```
C:\Users\you\dev\project\hello-world
```

Comment: Can you try a `git clone` on your local git repo ? Example : `git clone C:\Users\you\dev\project\hello-world`. You can do this test in a temporary directory. The objective is to check if your URL is correct or not. The expected result is that git successfully clone your repo in the temporary directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for jenkins that allows you to just use a folder rather than git or svn or another scm.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/File+System+SCM